# In Roblox Studio, does "save-to-roblox" also create/update a local file?

Tags: roblox

I have found that after I "Save to Roblox", I no longer have an option to "Save to File". Do I still have a local save file at this point that is updated when I "Save"?

[image: screen shot of roblox studio save menu]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. If your game are saved to your group, then you can't save it locally, Because you are connected to Team Create (by default)

If your game are saved to your profile, then the answer is Yes

Comment: Might this help.